# iText making a whole roll in table coloured

Tags: java, colors, jtable, itext

What's the simplest way to make a whole table row coloured in a PDF using iText? At the moment my code below only colours a specific cell in the table but I am not sure how to make the entire row coloured.

**Would appreciate if somebody can tell me how this is done but please do not post any code! I'd like to do the code myself.  Thanks**

```
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {

   for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {

    PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(myJTable.getValueAt(i, j).toString(), myFont));

        if (phrase.toString().contains("Test")) {
            cell.setBackgroundColor(BaseColor.RED); //I want to change the colour of 
            //the entire row containing a cell called "Test", not only the cell itself
        }

        pdfTable.addCell(cell);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the `PdfPRow` object already, you need to call `getCells()` on it, then iterate through the cells that come back, setting the colour of each.

If you don't have the `PdfPRow` already, you can get it via the `getTable` method of `PdfPCell` and the `getRow` method of `PdfPTable`.

Comment: Thanks man, seems I'm getting null when I call cell.getTable(), though? I made sure I do pdfTable.addCell(cell); before I actually call cell.getTable(). Do you know what could be causing this NullPointer exception?

Comment: No, I don't know.  But if you've already got the `pdfTable` variable, then you don't need to call `getTable`.  Just use the table that you've already got.

Comment: Perfect, that worked! thanks. Bit strange that I get null on cell.getTable(), though!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can directly. You can call [getRow(int)](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfPTable.html#getRow%28int%29) to get a given [PdfPRow](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfPRow.html), but there is no method in PdfPRow to set the fill (or background) color. You would then call [getCells()](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfPRow.html#getCells%28%29) on the row to then color all of that row (as in your example).

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to change the default cell color and keep it that way until you are done colouring cells.

```
table.getDefaultCell().setBackgroundColor(BaseColor.RED);        
table.addCell("1.0");
table.addCell("1.1");
table.addCell("1.2");    
table.getDefaultCell().setBackgroundColor(BaseColor.WHITE);
table.addCell("2.1");
table.addCell("2.2");
table.addCell("2.3");
```

There is also another way drawing a Rectangle. Check out this example [here](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=93).